# found : akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute [error] required: scala.util.Try

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to Scala and to akka i am trying to publish endpoint. Following compilation error is occurring.

```
 found: akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute
 [error]  required: scala.util.Try[Option[com.activegrid.entities.AuthSettings]] => (akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult])
```

Case class

```
case class AuthSettings(authType:String,authLevel:String,scope:String);
```

Enpoint

```
pathPrefix("config") {
       path("settings"/"auth") {
         post {
           entity(as[AuthSettings]) { authSettings =>
             val save: Future[AuthSettings] = persistance.persistAuthSettings(authSettings)
             onComplete(save) {
               complete("To insert app settings")
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

persistAuthSettings definition

```
def persistAuthSettings(authSettings: AuthSettings) : Future[AuthSettings] = Future {
    //Neo4j Operations
    authSettings;
```

}

What is going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onComplete` extracts the value from the future, and requires a function which operates on this value:

```scala
onComplete(save) { appSettings =>
  complete("To insert app settings")
}
```